# Bijection between $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, relations

How can we define bijection in between $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$? Even giving a injection from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and vice-versa will work.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290019/cardinality-of-mathbbr-and-mathbbr2

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Find a bijection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ or $\mathbb R\to\mathbb 2^{\mathbb N}$