# Finding an injective (1-1) map into a smaller interval?

Tags: real-analysis

As a side proof to a larger proof I am working on, I have to find an injective  (1-1) map $A\to B$ where $A = (0,1) \times (0,1)$ , $B= (0.5,0.6)$. How do you go about finding a a 1-1 map into a smaller interval like that.

Comment: Well, for example, the interval $(0,2)$ injects into the smaller interval $(0,\frac 12)$ by $x\mapsto \frac x4$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290136/prove-that-the-interval-0-1-and-the-cartesian-product-0-1-times-0-1 will help you get an injection from $A$ to $(0,1)$. Can you get from $(0,1)$ to $B$, Pablo?

Comment: I understand when both start at 0 and when one of them isnt "x cross y".

Comment: Gerry... I just need help finding an injective map between the A and B i gave

Comment: @PabloTores, If you have an injection $f:A \to (0,1)$, and another injection $g:(0,1)\to B$ then we can compose $f$ and $g$ to do the job you are looking for. The map $g$ should be not so hard but $f$ requires a little thinking.

Comment: Im confused so i need 2 maps?

Comment: It's just a composition of two maps. And you don't need to do it that way. It's just easier.

Comment: Actually, you might find it easiest to compose three maps; you can break the map from $(0,1)$ to $B$ up into a map from $(0,1)$ to $(0,0.1)$, follwed by a map from $(0,0.1)$ to $B$.